# Using Numpy creates a tcl folder when using py2exe

Tags: python, numpy, py2exe

When using `py2exe` on my Python program I get an executable, but also a `tcl\` folder.

This is strange, because I don't use `tcl/tk` at all and nothing related to `tkinter` in my code.

**Why importing `numpy` is responsible for adding this `tcl\` folder ? How to prevent this to happen ?**

---

**test.py**

```
import numpy

print 'hello'
```

---

**PY2EXE CODE**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(script_args = ['py2exe'],   windows=[{'script':'test.py'}], options = {'py2exe': {'compressed':1,'bundle_files': 1}}, zipfile = None)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Modulefinder` module which is used to determine dependencies gets "confused" and thinks you need `Tkinter`.

If you run following script...

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('test.py')
print finder.report()
```

...you will see found modules (shortened):

```
  Name                      File
  ----                      ----
m BaseHTTPServer            C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py
m ConfigParser              C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py
m FixTk                     C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py
m SocketServer              C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py
m StringIO                  C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.py
m Tkconstants               C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkconstants.py
m Tkinter                   C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py
m UserDict                  C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py
m _LWPCookieJar             C:\Python27\lib\_LWPCookieJar.py
...
```

So now we know that `Tkinter` is imported, but it is not very useful. The report does not show what is the offending module. However, it is enough information to exclude `Tkinter` by modifying py2exe script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(script_args = ['py2exe'],
      windows=[{'script':'test.py'}],
      options = {'py2exe': {'compressed':1,
                            'bundle_files': 1,
                            'excludes': ['Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']
                            },
                 },
      zipfile = None)
```

Usually that is enough. If you are still curious what modules are the offending ones, `ModuleFinder` is not much helpful. But you can install [`modulegraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modulegraph/0.10.4) and its dependency [`altgraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/altgraph/). Then you can run the following script and redirect the output to a HTML file:

```
import modulegraph.modulegraph

m = modulegraph.modulegraph.ModuleGraph()
m.run_script("test.py")
m.create_xref()
```

You will get dependency graph, where you will find that:

```
numpy -> numpy.lib -> numpy.lib.utils -> pydoc -> Tkinter
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. More generally : even with a soft *using* `Tkinter`, do you think it is possible to avoid the `tcl/` folder when using `py2exe` ?

Comment: I am not sure as I use `cx_freeze` and not `py2exe` which does not have "bundle to one exe" option. Theoretically you should be able to pack all files, even `/tcl` directory needed by `Tkinter` inside the exe.

Comment: There should be `bundle_files` option available for `py2exe`. May be helpful for that.